# Null value returned by a Google sheet regex

Tags: javascript, regex, google-sheets, null

I am trying to write a script in Google sheet that should extract a piece of a string using a regex.For example if I have "test test $1.00 test test" I would like to extract only "1.00"

What I have done so far is:

```
function myFunction() {
  var regExp = new RegExp("\$(.*)\s+");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var item_description = 0;
  var quantity = 1;
  var quantity_flat = [];
  var item_flat = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < values[quantity].length; j++) {
    if (values[quantity][j] == "") {
      quantity_flat.push(0);
    } else {
      quantity_flat.push(values[quantity][j]);
    }
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < values[item_description].length; j++) {
    var test = regExp.exec(values[item_description][j]);
    item_flat.push(test);
  }
}
```

When I check the type of test, I get that it is an Object and has a value of null.
Not sure where is the error. Ideally, I would like to get back a number so that I can push it in an array.
Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `new RegExp` unless you're creating the regexp dynamically, use a RegExp literal. You need to escape the backslashes in a string.

Comment: Use `console.log(regExp)` and you'll see the problem.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar for your help! I was able to solve this issue.
All I did was to modify the code in this way

var regExp = RegExp("\\$(.*)\\s+");

and then

item_flat.push(test[1]);

Comment: don't use `new RegExp`. Use `let regExp = /\$(.*)\s+/;`